# vb.net word cloud indexing

Tags: vb.net, image, listview, word-cloud

I use a `wordcloud` based on a list of words and their frequencies. I load the list from a text file and display them in a `Listview` and `image`. When the textfile is not indexed (the highest frequencies first) the word cloud doesn't make the words with the highest counts the biggest.
Is there a way to load the words, highest frequencies first, without having to change the list?

```
Imports WordCloudGen = WordCloud.WordCloud
Imports System.IO
Public Class WordCloud
    Private Sub WordCloud_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim lines = File.ReadLines("C:\Users\Gebruiker\Downloads\Words.txt")
        Dim Words As New List(Of String) '({100})
        Dim Frequencies As New List(Of Integer) '({100})
        Dim textValue As String()
        Dim items As New List(Of ListViewItem)

        For Each line In lines
            textValue = line.Split(New Char() {","})
            Words.Add(textValue(0))
            Frequencies.Add(Integer.Parse(textValue(1)))
            items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {textValue(0).ToString, textValue(1).ToString}, 0))
        Next
        ListView1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray)

        Dim wc As WordCloudGen = New WordCloudGen(600, 400)
        Dim i As Image = wc.Draw(Words, Frequencies)
        ResultPictureBox.Image = i

    End Sub
```

Comment: sounds complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the textfile is not indexed (the highest frequencies first) the word cloud doesn't make the words with the highest counts the biggest. Is there a way to load the words, highest frequencies first, without having to change the list?

I would recommend a new class to hold your data then you can sort anything you need much easier.

- Create a new class: `WordsFrequencies`

  ```
  Public Class WordsFrequencies

   Public Property Word As String
   Public Property Frequency As Integer

  End Class
  ```
- Change your `WordCloud_Load` routine as below:

  ```
   Dim WordsFreqList As New List(Of WordsFrequencies)
   For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("C:\Users\Gebruiker\Downloads\Words.txt")
       Dim splitText As String() = line.Split(","c)
       If splitText IsNot Nothing AndAlso splitText.Length = 2 Then
           Dim wordFrq As New WordsFrequencies
           Dim freq As Integer
           wordFrq.Word = splitText(0)
           wordFrq.Frequency = If(Integer.TryParse(splitText(1), freq), freq, 0)
           WordsFreqList.Add(wordFrq)
       End If
   Next
   If WordsFreqList.Count > 0 Then
       ' Order the list based on the Frequency
       WordsFreqList = WordsFreqList.OrderByDescending(Function(w) w.Frequency).ToList
       ' Add the sorted items to the listview
       WordsFreqList.ForEach(Sub(wf)
                                 ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {wf.Word, wf.Frequency.ToString}, 0))
                             End Sub)
   End If
  ```

In the above, I would recommend doing a simple `For` loop with `File.ReadLines`, this is so you don't have to load the whole file in memory if you're just getting data and parsing it. I'm using the [OrderByDescending Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=net-5.0) which is part of `System.Linq` namespace.

As far as this: `Dim i As Image = wc.Draw(Words, Frequencies)` you then could do something like:

```
 Dim i As Image = wc.Draw(WordsFreqList.Select(Function(wf) wf.Word), WordsFreqList.Select(Function(wf) wf.Frequency))
```

This will project the `Word`'s into an `IEnumerable(String)` and then `Frequency` into an `IEnumerable(Integer)`.

Comment: Error message: System.InvalidCastException: "Unable to convert an object of type WhereSelectListIterator`2 [listview_db.WordsFrequencies, System.String] to type System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [System.String]."

Comment: If on `Dim i As Image = wc.Draw(WordsFreqList.Select(Function(wf) wf.Word), WordsFreqList.Select(Function(wf) wf.Frequency))`, just add the `ToList` to the end of each `Select`. So it would become: `Dim i As Image = wc.Draw(WordsFreqList.Select(Function(wf) wf.Word).ToList, WordsFreqList.Select(Function(wf) wf.Frequency).ToList)`.

Comment: wordFrq when filled turns out to have the word and frequency lilke this: william10. The image is not displayed

Comment: Is there supposed to be a space?

Comment: no space, but words and frequency should be seperated

Comment: @Marco so each on a new line?

Comment: What about `ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {wf.Word, wf.Frequency.ToString}, 0))`? I may have misinterpreted what you were doing here.

Comment: Thats working for the Listview but the image is still not drawn

Comment: Was the image drawn before?

Comment: yes it was drawn before with a List of String and List of Integer

Comment: My mistake, I forgot one additional line:   ResultPictureBox.Image = i